# Running tests in a spec in a sequence

Tags: geb

Is there a way to run the tests within a spec in sequence?

```
@Stepwise
class TestSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def 'A'(){
        //
    }

    def 'B'(){
        //
    }

    def 'C'(){
        //
    }

}
```

Is there a way I can force A to run before B and B to run before C?

Thanks,
Shravanthi

Comment: Stepwise annotation is responsible for this. Your example should run in a sequence.

Comment: Could you run the tests sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

It should run in this order but with @Stepwise, you will keep the session between the features.